# Eclipse Neon - cursor jumps, view disappears

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I downloaded and installed Eclipse Neon yesterday on my MacBook Air.

If I start programming and click randomly in the editing area the whole Java view magically disappears and I am only left with a grey area. Only when I click the view on the very right side it appears again.

Also while typing the cursor suddenly jumps to the very beginning of the file, continuing to write there.

Does anyone have an explanation or solution for this weird behavior?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are not just maximizing the editor area? Can you show an image?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. i randomly click in the editing area, in the code and suddenly the view closes. I don't think an image will be of a lot value... as it is literally just randomly opening and closing the java view (it is like clicking this java view button on the very right,  without clicking it).

Comment: All I can say is that Eclipse Neon works fine for me on Mac OS X 10.11.6 on a 27" iMac.